# How to create record with belongsTo relationship in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to save relationship between the two models via select.
My models:

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

Animal = DS.Model.extend {
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  nameEng: DS.attr 'string'

  animalType: DS.belongsTo 'animalType'
}

`export default Animal`

`import DS from 'ember-data'`

AnimalType = DS.Model.extend {
  title: DS.attr 'string'

  animals: DS.hasMany('animal')
}
`export default AnimalType`
```

Route:

```
AnimalsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.createRecord 'animal'
```

Controller:

```
AnimalsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  animalTypes: (-> 
    @store.find 'animalType'
  ).property()

  actions:
    createAnimal: ->
      @get('model').save().then (animal) =>
        console.log(animal.id)
```

And my select in emblem:

```
= view "select" content=animalTypes optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title"
```

On server I get this json:

```
{
  "animal"=>{
              "name"=>"some string", 
              "name_eng"=>"some string", 
              "animal_type_id"=>nil
            }
}
```

How to set animal type?

Comment: Which `Adapter` do you use? Do you use embedded records? (I can't see async: true). Could you possibly setup a demo? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: Im use `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this solution works:

```
view "select" selection=model.animalType content=animalTypes optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title"
```

Use `selection` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to me that you're missing binding selected value on Em.Select.
Could you trying to binding:

```
view "select" value=model.animalType content=animalTypes optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title"
```

Comment: Its not work for me( and I had an erorr `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'animalType' record to this relationship `